# How can I to display photo in modal?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-hooks

I have problem with send choose object photo to show in modal? Somobody know what I'm wrong to do? I have.

When I click on Image then I get an object but it does not put a picture inside I do not know what is missing?

With arrays I have a huge problem I can not understand why the object being sent is not displayed, I will be grateful for suggestions and answers.

Arrays

```
const dataImage = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Letniskowy Pałac Branickich',
    img: 'branicki.jpg'
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    name: 'W drodze do Torunia',
    img: 'roadTorun.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Kładki w Śliwnie',
    img: 'sliwnoKladki.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Sopockie Molo',
    img: 'sopotMolo.jpg'
  }
]
```

My Main Component

```
export default function FlexPanelGallery () {
    const [imagesToGallery] = useState(dataImage);
    const [grayscale, setGrayscale] = useState(0);
    const [selectedPhoto, setSelectedPhoto] = useState();
    const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
    const [subtitle, setSubTitle] = useState('');
    const [modalMainOpen, setModalMainOpen] = useState(false);
    const [pic, setPic] = useState();
    const makeGrey = {
      filter: `grayscale(${grayscale})`
    }

    function toggleModal (pic) {
      setModalMainOpen(true)
      setPic(pic);
      console.log('What is pass! ' + pic)
      return pic
    }
   let photoList = imagesToGallery;
   console.log(photoList);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container" style={makeGrey}>        
        {photoList.map((img, i)=> (
          <ImageThumb 
            img={img.img} 
            key={i} 
            name={img.name} 
            onActivePhoto={toggleModal.bind(this, img.img)}
            />
        ))}    
      </div>
      <div style={buttonStyle}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => setGrayscale(4)} >Grayscale</Button>
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={() => setGrayscale(0)} >Normal</Button>
      </div>
{/* When I click this button then i have image in tag <img />  */}
      {/* <button onClick={toggleModal.bind(this, 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/business/1')} >Click</button> */}


      <button onClick={e => toggleModal(pic)}>Trigger Modal</button>
        <Modal bg="#222" show={ modalMainOpen } 
            onClose={toggleModal.bind(this) }>
            <img src={pic} />
            {pic}
        </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { show, bg, closeModal } = this.props;
    // Custom styles: set visibility and backbround color
    const styles = {
      modal: {
        display: (show) ? null : 'none', 
        backgroundColor: bg || 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',       
      }
    };

    return (
      <div className="modal-wrapper" style={styles.modal}>
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign modal-item"
            onClick={this.props.onClose}></span>
        <div className="modal-item">
            { this.props.children}
                </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Empty component where I'm inserting data

```
const ImageThumb = (props) => (
    <div className="cardImage">
      <div className="box">
        <img src={require('./Images/' + props.img)} alt={props.name} onClick={props.onActivePhoto} />
      </div>
      <div className="thumbTitle">{props.name}</div>
    </div> 
);
```

When I click on Image then I get an object but it does not put a picture inside I do not know what is missing?
[image: Effect object passed]

EDIT: 
This is result in this case: https://scherlock90.github.io/flex-panel-gallery/

Comment: is it possible to share the project via git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to include an image dynamically. But your image path points to `./Images/roadTorun.jpg`.

How would a program running in a browser recognize this path?

```
src/FlexComponents/Flex-panel-gallery.js Line 78

<img src={pic} />
```

if you want to locate an image dynamically, you need to move your `Images` folder into the `output bundle` directory. In your case its `public` directory

#### Make below changes to your project

- Move the `Images` directory from `src/FlexComponents/Images` to `public/Images`
- In `Flex-panel-gallery.js`, update `toggleModel` method in `line 45` with below code

```
function toggleModal (pic) {
      setModalMainOpen(true)
      setPic('/Images/'+pic);      
}
```

- In `Flex-panel-gallery.js`, update `line 114` to below code

```
<img src={'/Images/' + props.img} alt={props.name} onClick={props.onActivePhoto} />
```

Verify if this fixes your problem

**Note**

You weren't facing any issue with displaying images using your current code on `line 114`

```
<img src={require('./Images/' + props.img)} alt={props.name} onClick={props.onActivePhoto} />
```

This is because you've included image path statically, so webpack imported the image during `build time`, that is why the images were rendered in `ImageThumb` component

Below path in your `ImageThumb` component was created by webpack during `build` time as you have given your exact image path to `src` in `img` tag
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I still have a question, if I wanted to have all the images in src? is there any other path to building a component and case number two or is it better to store images in public or in src? because I was aware of the fact that I was being photographed statically, but I could not understand why I was not getting the same photos on.

Comment: When I want to hosting result then I have in console status 404 and none image load but when I change code in function setPic(require('./Images/'+pic)); to adding dot and require then all is fine :P I little change your's sugestion 
but without your guidance I would not have thought I could do it :-)

Comment: `static import` - webpack is aware during `build time` that you will be using an image and webpack will scan all the js files for `imported or required` images  using `file-loader` and optimize it and place it in a different path as i have mentioned in the answer. if its a `dynamic import`, during `build time` webpack wouldn't know as `pic` in `require('/Images/'+pic)` will be null during `build time` . So, any images placed inside `src` will not be loaded, this is why you got blank image in your `modal`. This why you have to move the `images` into `public` folder from src

Comment: Ok, but when I set in function toggleModal this code -> setPic(require('./Images/'+pic)) and I have folder Images in src ; then everything works well. And on the github host it works fine.

Comment: you were using your own `Modal` component while you were facing the issue. try using the same to reproduce what i'm saying.. now you've replaced your own `Modal` with `ReactModal` provided by `react`. whenever you load an image on your `ReactModal`, you can see in your `network` tab on chrome devtools that a request to your server is being done. This wasn't the case when you used `Modal`.

Comment: But I would like to thank you without your help, I would not go any further